# SAS size of subset not matching expected frequency

Tags: sas, subset, frequency

I create a simple subset of a sas dataset with a single condition where durrel_cyc = 1. This creates a set of 376 observations. However when I run a frequency of vdurrel_cyc, there are 536 (unweighted) observations with the value of 1 that should have been selected.

I'm not sure how I can create a working example as it is clearly illogical and I've never come across this before - and I've been using SAS awhile.

I'm really not sure what to do and it's driving me crazy. Is there any command which could cause this?

I tried the following :

```
data a b ;
set look ;
if durrel_cyc = 1 then output a ; else output b ;
run ;
```

[image]

```
proc freq data=b ;
tables durrel_cyc / missing ;
run ;
```

[image]

Why are there still values of 1 in dataset B ?

Comment: There is no way this is not working. You are sure there are no steps between this data step and proc freq? Could you provide data sample?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't say how durrel_cyc was created, so one possibility is that it is a victim of a numerical representation error (there are numerous articles on the internet about this).

Try putting `if round(durrel_cyc) = 1 then output a ; else output b ;` to see if that fixes the problem.

If that doesn't work then just check that durrel_cyc doesn't have a custom format associated with it (`proc freq` will display the formatted values, so if there's a custom format that displays a different number as 1, `proc freq` will show this as 1)

Comment: Thanks Keith. Round() does the trick, I read up on numerical representation error and as durrel_cyc is a sum of various other variables the error occurred. Surprising to me that summing integers only would produce such an error.

Comment: Summing integers wouldn't cause this problem, so I suspect that one of the other variables has been derived from some non-integers